# How to apply a theme using charts_flutter?

Tags: flutter, charts, material-design, themes

Is it possible to apply an app-wide Theme for charts using the charts_flutter package. For instance, can I define a theme in a ThemeData widget using Material Design that updates the title text theme of all the charts in my widget tree (similar to what we can do with textTheme, appBarTheme etc)?

```
titleStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(///current way to customize for each chart)
```

```
ThemeData(

textTheme: const TextTheme().copyWith(
        bodyText2:
        const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),

/// are there properties that can be set in here that will update the default theme of the charts similar to how this is done with say setting a text theme.
);
```

Package link: [flutter charts](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter)

Comment: Can you link the package and provide more example code?

Comment: Sure, provided more info. Thanks